# War der Fortbestand des Konjunktivs in der deutschen Sprache je bedroht?

Tags: subjunctive, history, reference-request

Daniel Scholten von [Belles Lettres](http://www.belleslettres.eu/#konjunktiv) schreibt dieses:

> Vor dreißig Jahren schienen die Tage des Konjunktivs in der deutschen Sprache gezählt. Nun ist er wieder da – stärker denn je.

Ich kann mich daran erinnern, dass unser Deutschlehrer auch vom Untergang des Konjunktivs klagte, aber ich habe das eher auf die flektierenden Formen bezogen und evtl. dass der Konjunktiv I in der indirekten Rede ausstürbe. Scholten macht keine derartige Einschränkung.

Wurde das je ernsthaft befürchtet und von wem?

Comment: Naja, bei Belles Lettres handelt es sich ja überwiegend einerseits um Wunschdenken, andererseits um präskriptive Sprachkritik, gewürzt mit etwas linguistischer Substanz, passend für die selbstgewählte Zielgruppe der konservativ-elitären „Dichter und Denker“. Beim Überfliegen habe ich jedenfalls keinen Hinweis auf empirische Untermauerung der oben zitierten Behauptung gefunden. Sie dient lediglich zur Einleitung und Rechtfertigung der Tutorials. Google Ngrams zu [Hilfsverben](http://goo.gl/qz5LNa) und [häufigen starken Vollverben](http://goo.gl/A6JQ7P) stützen weder (aber eher) Tod noch Boom.

Comment: @Crissov: Deiner Kritik an BL stimme ich zu und ich verstehe auch nicht, wieso das regelmäßig rumgereicht wird wie geschnitten Brot. Die folgende Behauptung, dass der Konjunktiv in 9 von 10 Fällen falsch verwendet ist, ist jedenfalls unbelegter Humbug. Das mit dem Konjunktiv kam aber wie gesagt auch von einer zweiten Quelle, insofern dachte ich, dass das mal analog zu "Der Dativ ist dem Genitiv sein Tod" ein Thema war, begründet oder nicht.

Comment: Die Annahme, dass der Konjunktiv aussterbe, findet sich auch in Sicks [Zwiebelfisch](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-der-traurige-konjunktiv-a-329309.html) und ist auch sonst anekdotisch fundiertes Allgemeinwissen. Meine Hypothese ist eher, dass das klassisch-humanistische Wissen um die tote Lateingrammatik stetig sinkt und im Zuge dessen ihr Einfluss auf die Grammatikbeschreibung anderer Sprachen zunehmend hinterfragt wird, d.h. der Konjunktiv war im Deutschen vielleicht nie so wichtig oder systematisch wie die Grammatikbücher Schülern und Lehrern weismachen wollten.

Comment: Man kann durchaus empirisch beobachten, dass der Konjunktiv in der gesprochenen Sprache gerne durch den Indikativ ersetzt wird. Nur ob das dann gleich zu Existenzängsten führen muss ...

Comment: @dirkt: Aber wohl kaum Konjunktiv II.

Comment: @Veredomon: Auch der Konjunktiv II, wenn auch weniger oft, und dabei meine ich nicht das Ersetzen durch "würde". Achte einfach mal drauf, wenn du mit Leuten redest. :-)

Comment: Bei meiner Mutter (fränkisch) ist mir eine Konjunktivform im Dialekt aufgefallen, die mich erstaunte. Sie sagte: Des tätert ich net ( Das würde ich nicht tun/täte ich nicht). Bemerkenswert insofern als die lateinischen Endungen für Konjunktiv Imperfekt - aret (amare/amaret), -eret (mone:re/mone:ret, regere/regeret) oder -iret (audire/audiret) sind. Da findet sich also im fränkischen Dialekt und wahrscheinlich auch in anderen Dialekten eine Konjunktivendung, die fast genau mit der lateinischen Endung übereinstimmt. Da sehe ich für ein Aussterben des Konjunktivs keine Anzeichen.

Comment: Ich glaube mich zu erinnern, dass die Form des Konjunktiv 2 mit "würde" (*er sagte, er würde kommen*) in meiner frühen Schulzeit nicht als "richtiger" Konjunktiv galt (Korrigiert mich, wenn ich da falsch liege). Heute ist das als Konjunktiv akzeptiert und hat im Alltagsgebrauch viele "ältere" Konjunktivformen abgelöst und "darf" auch in geschriebenem Text und nicht nur in der Umgangssprache vorkommen . Möglicherweise meinen die Verkünder des Aussterbens ja diese Verdrängung.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gemäss [indirekte Rede « atlas-alltagssprache](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-3/f08e/) ist der Konjunktiv präsens in der Alltagssprache in Deutschland und Österreich weitgehend unüblich. Dies liefert eine gute Erklärung für die Unsicherheit im gehobenen Stil, wo der Konjunktiv präsens verwendet werden sollte: Wer den Konjunktiv präsens im Alltag nicht verwendet, wird oft kein Gespür für die Verwendung haben.

Der Grund für die Unüblichkeit des Konjunktivs präsens in der Alltagssprache dürfte wohl darin liegen, dass die Form weitgehend mit dem Indikativ präsens zusammengefallen ist – einer Verbform wie *ich mache* ist nicht anzusehen, ob sie nun im Indikativ oder im Konjunktiv steht. Ein deutlicher Unterschied zeigt sich nur bei der dritten Person singular: *es macht – es mache*. Anders verhält es sich bei den hochalemannischen Dialekten in der Schweiz, wo der Konjunktiv *i(ch) machi* deutlich vom Indikativ *i(ch) mache* zu unterscheiden ist. Dies dürfte der Grund dafür sein, dass in der Schweiz der Konjunktiv präsens auch in der Alltagssprache üblich bleibt.

Ähnlich wie beim Konjunktiv präsens verhält es sich übrigens auch beim Präteritum. In der südlichen Hälfte des deutschen Sprachraums wird es in der Alltagssprache nicht verwendet, da es lautlich weitgehend mit dem Präsens zusammengefallen ist – das Präsens *er macht* ist vom Präteritum *er macht’* nicht zu unterscheiden (vgl. [Oberdeutscher Präteritumschwund – Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oberdeutscher_Pr%C3%A4teritumschwund)). Da das Präteritum im Alltag nicht verwendet wird, fehlt oft ein Gespür für die Verwendung. So kommt es im gehobenen Stil, wo das Präteritum verwendet werden sollte, zu Unsicherheiten (insbesondere in der Abgrenzung zum Perfekt).

Ist der Konjunktiv bedroht? Der Konjunktiv präsens wird von vielen Deutschsprachigen nur noch in gehobenem Stil verwendet, wobei dann halt oft das Gespür für die richtige Verwendung fehlt. In der Alltagssprache ist der Konjunktiv präsens in Deutschland und Österreich weitgehend verschwunden. Da gibt es also gar kein Verschwinden mehr zu befürchten, denn der Konjunktiv präsens ist bereits verschwunden.

Anders verhält es sich beim Konjunktiv präteritum. Meines Wissens existiert diese Form in allen Varietäten der deutschen Alltagssprache, auch im Süden, wo es keinen Indikativ präteritum gibt. Sie unterscheidet sich deutlich vom Indikativ, und zwar sowohl vom Indikativ präsens als auch – sofern vorhanden – vom Indikativ präteritum. Von einem Verschwinden habe ich noch nie gehört.

Comment: Es erscheint mir so, als ob Du die überzeugendste Antwort habest.

Answer (score -3):

Ich habe keine direkten Quellen, aber meine Vermutung ist die Beschleunigung der Kommunikation. Um im Konjunktiv zu reden muss man um die Ecke denken und um die Ecke denken kostet Zeit.

Ich schätze mal mit dem Aufkommen von Facebook und anderen Medien, die längere schriftliche Ausführungen erlauben, hat sich auch der Anteil der langsameren Kommunikation wieder erhöht.

Den vorherigen Verfall würde ich dem Fernsehen zuschreiben, Einwegkommunikation.

Comment: Die Erklärung wird leider mit diversen falschen Annahmen belegt: 1) das gleiche Phänomen sei in anderen Sprachen zu beobachten die genau so gut Fernsehen usw haben 2) Effizienz sei ein Ziel der Sprecher 3) der Untergang einer grammatikalischen Zeit sei effizienter... usw usf.